# Not being able to add fields because of Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have created relation between category table and news table.The id for new_category that I am inserting in news table do exists in table categories, the character type of both of the column are same and still I am receiving the following issue:

> 2018-12-28 06:32:49 AM, Insert Query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`demo`.`news`, CONSTRAINT `fk_news` FOREIGN KEY (`news_category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE).

Comment: You need to remove foreign key first to do this stuff.

Comment: You may have old stale data in one or more tables which has a integrity constraint problem.  If you add some sample data for the relevant tables, maybe someone can help.

Comment: @Amit Rajput I removed foreign keys and recreated it but that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure that you have not declared the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.**

This may occur due to one of the following reasons

1. The FOREIGN KEY value must be unique in the table.
2. The size and sign of integer types must be the same.
3. Foreign key value in a child table should have a matching candidate key value in the parent table.
4. Proper cascading between parent and child table
5. Columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

Reference :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: I just set child table (news_category) to NOT NULL and now I am not being able to cascade them. Moreover, now I get this error: >Insert Query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`shikshak`.`news`, CONSTRAINT `news_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`news_category`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`))

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/error-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1452-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails?page=1

Comment: you can add 6th point on the reason    Cannot create Foreign key on delete set null in not null field